# whats my ip in google gives me my Ip. If I put that as a inbound rule in a AWS RDS Security group, will that allow access to my computer only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I code, this networking stuff is hard.

I want it where I can run django migrations from my laptop to a aws RDS instance.

I type whats my ip in google I get my ip.

now if I put that IP address directly as it is. `example: 127.0.0.1`

in an inbound rule in an aws security group and I apply that security group to my RDS instance.

Will that allow my computer, and my computer only for that security group to access my database?

Answer (score 3):

If your IP address is the only IP address in all of the security groups associated with that Amazon RDS database, then it will be **the only IP address permitted to communicate with the database**.

However, notice that I didn't say "your computer". This is because **your IP address is potentially shared with other devices on the same network** (eg your home network or your office network, or even your mobile phone network).

This due to the concept of public/private IP addresses and the fact that IPv4 doesn't have enough IP addresses. If we were all using IPv6, then it would likely be true. However, in this world of IPv4, the public IP address is **only used when network traffic exits a network and enters the Internet**. This might be via a corporate network gateway, or your home router.

So, only your IP address will be permitted, but **there might be multiple devices** that "appear" on the Internet to have that IP address. As long as you trust your network, then it is reliable enough for your database security.

Comment: dude your making this way more complicated then you need to and its my failure because I didn't make it clear. I have other security groups. I am talking about adding another security group just for my computer. So Im just asking about this specific security group

Comment: If _any_ attached security group permits the access, then traffic will be allowed through. They are "additive".

Answer (score 2):

First thing you're RDS needs to be in public subnet which is most likely not!

If it is private subnet then adding IP in SG is of no use!

If in public Subnet then append your IP with /32 as it'll allow only that specific IP instead of a range.

For migrations you can make use of yoyo kindda stuffs which will ease our job!